# Latex: Multiple \cite's with an 'and' before the last reference

Tags: citing

I'm using Natbib and BibTeX writing my thesis.

If I say:

```
\citet{key1,key2,key3} did something big.
```

I get:

```
Key1 Author (2014); Key2 Author (2011); Key3 Author (1900) did something big.
```

Is there a formatting command that might give me an "and" before the last reference? That it might look like this:

```
Key1 Author (2014); Key2 Author (2011) and Key3 Author (1900) did something big.
```

I know that I can go:

```
\citet{key1,key2} and \citet{key3} did something big
```

but that kinda seems hacky. I was wondering if anyone knows some LaTeX magic that will make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to make a full sentence with the subject noun consisting of three groups of cited authors, I think you should write

```
\citet{key1}, \citet{key2}, and \citet{key3} did something big.
```

Otherwise you run the risk that `natbib`'s sorting algorithm will place the citation callout for `key2` ahead of the one for `key1`. If the inverted ordering should happen to be the ordering you actually want, you should make sure it's done that way explicitly, i.e., by having three separat `\citet` commands.